# Viewing the status of scheduled query in big query using list_transfer_configs

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a cloud function which will check for status of certain scheduled queries in order to trigger another process. I am trying to use below in main.py

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
from google.cloud import bigquery_datatransfer
def extract_data(event, context):
    transfer_client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient()
    project_id = "projects/whr-asia-datalake-nonprod"
    configs = transfer_client.list_transfer_configs(parent=project_id)
    print("Got the following configs:")
    for config in configs:
      print(f"\tID: {config.name}, Schedule: {config.schedule}")
```

in requirements.txt, I have added below code

```
google-cloud-bigquery-datatransfer==1
google-cloud-bigquery==1
```

[image]

getting empty response as shown above. I have scheduled queries that have run today. What could be the issue?

Comment: I actually used your code as a base, and it is working for me, although I have not tried it on a CF, could you run this script on your cloud shell and check what it throws to you?

Comment: I had a similar issue, I think the location defaults to the US, so if you've got queries in the EU/ASIA then they're not visible. Can't see anything in the docs for location

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but could see only a few of the queries. Turned out it only pulled queries from the US by default.

https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/8466#issuecomment-610772303

Not sure if it's your issue exactly but adding the location to the project and it should pull from other regions.

```
def get_scheduled_queries():
    transfer_client = bigquery_datatransfer.DataTransferServiceClient()
    parent = transfer_client.common_project_path(project_id + "/locations/EU")
    configs = transfer_client.list_transfer_configs(parent=parent)
    for config in configs:
```